# Program accuracy varying by parameters

Tags: c++, integer, integer-overflow

I am trying to learn how to program in C++, so I created something that allowed to you enter a minimum, and maximum parameter, and it will compute `k+(k+1)+(k+2)+...+(max)`, and compared it to the analytical value, using the standard formula `(n(n+1)/2)`. It seems to work fine when I try small numbers, but when, for example, trying `min=4`, `max=4*10^5` (400,000), I get a negative result for the sum, but a positive result checking with the analytical method, even after changing the type from 'int' to 'long'. Trying other combinations, I have achieved the opposite, with the analytical method resulting in a negative sum. I suspect this is related to the fact the type `int` can go up to a certain number of digits, but I wanted some confirmation on that, and if it isn't, what the actual problem is. The code is provided below:

```
#include <iostream>
// Values are inconsistent when paramin,parammax become large. 
// For example, try (parammin,parammax)=(4,400,000)
int main() {
    int parammax,parammin;
    std::cout << "Input a minimum, then maximum parameter to sum up to" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> parammin >> parammax;
    int sum=0;
    for (int iter = parammin; iter <= parammax; iter++){
        sum += iter;
    }
    std::cout << "The sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
    const int analyticalmethod = (parammax*(parammax+1)-parammin*(parammin-1))/2;
    std::cout << "The analytical result for the sum is,"
                 " via (max*(max+1)-min*(min-1))/2: " 
              << analyticalmethod << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It does sound like overflow, try changing to `long long`, that should work for your max (4,000,000), but will also fail later on. `int` and `long` are often the same thing.

Comment: I didn't realize there was a long long. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks! Now it's just super slow, gotta figure that part out! ( By this I mean when running it in Code::Blocks it takes quite a while to compile and send the initial cout when it first opens the command prompt), and even running it itself from the command prompt takes a minute to display the first cout

Comment: Beware, SO in not Mathematics! Specifically, MathJax is not implemented here, and because of that, the question is barely readable. I had to copy it in a Mathematics question to understand it. TL/DR: do not use MathJax on SO.

Comment: It doesn't? That must be a TeX extension I added to my Google Chrome, It displayed properly when it showed me what my message was going to look like, so I kind of assumed it would. Thanks for the tip though, and sorry about that. Does my edit make it more clear @SergeBallesta ?

Comment: @Shinaolord It shouldn't be that slow to write the first output. After that, computing a sum whose analytical results is trivial will of course be inefficient, but the first output should be instant.

Comment: I think I figured out what I was doing to make it appear slower, it sems to have went anyway. Thank you for the help,though @Qubit

Comment: I have reformatted your text a little to improve readability, and (I believe) improved your code a little.  The code changes are a little bit more than fixing indentation and removing horizontal scrollbars, so if you want to revert them feel free. I switched the `while` loop to a more idiomatic `for` loop, changed `iterator` to `iter` (because the SO syntax highlighting was treating `iterator` as a keyword), and initialized `analyticalmethord` rather than assigned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using very large numbers without control is dangerous in C++. The basic types `int`, `long` and `long long` are implementation dependant, with only the following requirements:

- `int` is at least 16 bits large
- `long` is at least as large as `int` and at least 32 bits large
- `long long` is at least as large as `long` and at least 64 bits large

If you think you can need larger values, you should considere a multi precision library like the excellent [gmp](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: Thank you. I'm new with this, used to much higher level languages, such as Mathematica, which has built-in infinite precision, and Matlab. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Although it is true that `int` is not required to be longer than 16 bits, *in practise* it will be exactly 32 bits (unless you are compiling for a low-power embedded device).  (Also, roughly speaking, `long` is 32 bits on Windows and either 32 or 64 bits everywhere else, depending on whether you compile for 32 bit or 64 bit pointers.)